# Symfony 4 form - How to get the children element of parent inside subform

Tags: forms, symfony4, addeventlistener

I'm trying to have list of cities based on the region and also the birth date of a person.
That is why in my code I tried to do this :

```php
 $builder->get('region')->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
                $data = $event->getForm()->getData();

                $birthDate = $event->getForm()->getParent()->getData();

                //formModifier where I am adding the $form->add('city'...
                $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $data, $birthDate);
            }
        );
```

However the data I get from $event->getForm()->getParent()->getData() doesn't render the data that I want, it gets the value of the preset data instead of the submitted one.

When I do a dump of $event->getForm()->getParent() I can see that the data that I want to target is in children and that the data that it is currently sending me when I add getData() is in model data.

```php
Symfony\Component\Form\Form {#2290 ▼
  -config: Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder {#2330 ▶}
  -parent: null
  -children: Symfony\Component\Form\Util\OrderedHashMap {#2329 ▶}
  -errors: []
  -submitted: false
  -clickedButton: null
  -modelData: array:2 [▶]
  -normData: array:2 [▶]
  -viewData: array:2 [▶]
  -extraData: []
  -transformationFailure: null
  -defaultDataSet: true
  -lockSetData: false
  -name: "information_salarie"
  -inheritData: false
  -propertyPath: null
}
```

I tried to use getChildren() but it says that it doesn't know the method. How can I access the data inside the children element ?

The birth date is in a DateTime input just before the region one. I need it so that I can get the name of the cities at the period the person was born if it's different from the current name.

Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 2):

You can't access parent data from a child event listener: form submit is started on root form that subsequently calls the `submit` method on all the children forms just after firing the `PRE_SUBMIT` event.

If you want to modify a child form based on a parent data, you can only use the `PRE_SUBMIT` event on the parent form.

Ex:

```php
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $e) {
    $data = $e->getData();
    $form = $e->getForm();

    if ($data['birth_date'] === '1900-05-01') {
        $form->add('city', CityType::class);
    }
});
```

Note that if you have to change type/options on an already added field, you have to remove it first.